# The UITableViewCell's width and height always is 320 and 44

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm sorry for my shoddy English.
A cell named 'A' contains a subTableView;The 'A' is normal,but the subCell's frame.size always is (320,44).
show the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* cellID = @"OrderViewControllerCellID";
    OrderTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[OrderTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    OrderCellModel* model = self.orderDataSourceArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.model = model;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    return cell;
}
```

'A'cell contentView

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        _productsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _productsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _productsTableView.delegate = self;
        _productsTableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_productsTableView];
        _productsTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* cellID = @"OrderTableViewSubCellID";
    OrderSubTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[OrderSubTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    OrderProductModel* model = _productsArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.model = model;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _productsArray.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return transForHeight(86.f);
}
```

[image]

thank you for looking at my question.
I'm sorry for my little English again.

Comment: yes. it's always return height of cell 44. if you want to change then implement heightforrowatindexpath method.

Comment: I don't think the _auto-layout_ has been set up properly for your cell's  content view; and seeing your screenshot it seems that not even the _autoresize-mask_ has been set up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initWithStyle` allways returns cells with height of 44 unless you overwrite it in a subclass. You should change height in delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I'll try your suggestion。

Comment: If this answer helps, please accept this as the correct answer by select the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

default cell height is `44.0`. You need to override `heightforrowatindexpath` method.